# Navbar not updating username after login with another account

Tags: angular

I am creating login page,data is coming from database.i have used 2 login account. i login with one username and then in navbar i am displaying username, after when i logged out and login with another username it is showing the previous username. and when i press f5 then it is displaying correct username, pls help me i dont want to refresh the page.

in navbar component i am fetching data in ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
        if(this.auth.loggedIn()){
            this.auth.getProfile().subscribe(profile=>{
                this.user=profile.user;
            },
            err=>{
                console.log(err);
                return false;
            });
        }
}
```

here's template

```
  <li *ngIf="auth.loggedIn()">
          <a href="#>{{user?.name | uppercase}}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: try disabling the browser cache and do you have any serverside caching enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use the username from your auth service if you create a variable and save it there.
For example in your Auth Service

```
   currentUser:any;
    ...
    // Your login implementation and save it to this.currentUser
```

**Before**

```
     <li *ngIf="auth.loggedIn()">
          <a href="#>{{user?.name | uppercase}}</a>
     </li>
```

**After**

```
      <li *ngIf="auth.loggedIn()">
              <a href="#>{{auth.currentUser?.name | uppercase}}</a>
      </li>
```

Comment: Thanks, Its Working.. :)

Comment: @GauravUmrani glad it helped you. Mark this as a solution so that others can see

Answer (score 0):

you face the error, because, when your Navbar component Init, it will get your user info only once, so when you login with another account, the "User Info" does not change.

you need some how notify the Component that you change User Info.

I suggest create "EventEmitter like" event with Sub

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  profile$: Subject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
  constructor() { }
  emit(value: any) {
    this.profile$.next(value);
  }
  get profile(): BehaviorSubject<any> {
    return this.profile$ as BehaviorSubject<any>;
  }

  login(credential) {
    // after login successful, for example
    this.emit({user: yourUserInfoObject})
  }
}
```

in your "navbar component"

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.profile.subscribe(profile=>{
        this.user = profile.user;
    },
    err=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```